# Make my xamarin forms app able to open specific file types?

Tags: forms, file, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building my first app with Xamarin forms, an EPUB reader. The core app is now working well and able to render documents. The question I am trying to answer is how I can register for my app as a handler for the EPUB document type so that if the file is opened from an email app my reader app will be available as a reader?

Ideally this should be a cross platform solution.

Thanks!

Comment: This is too broad a question for SO. Please break down your question and add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Andrew, I'm also looking for a similar Xamarin.form solution . Can you please update if you get succeed with this question from anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally this should be a cross platform solution.

Unfortunately, there is no cross platform solution that you can use to register to read the file types.

You will need to follow the platform specifications for that, 
iOS https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/custom-document-types/

Android https://gist.github.com/brendanzagaeski/70afe08654927befb26b