# Xamarin: Create new file extension

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app which needs data to be shared with other users.
I need to create new file type extension like pti or sbd. I want android/ios to know that my app can open these files.
For sharing I am using Xamarin Essentials Share.RequestAsync.

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried so far? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try to directly create the file name with new extension in the file path as mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#saving-and-loading-files). There is an example of creating '.txt' file.

Comment: When someone clicks a .json file on a cell phone, I want them to get my app as an option to open that file.

Comment: Ideally this should be a cross platform solution.

Unfortunately, there is no cross platform solution that you can use to register to read the file types.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222259/make-my-xamarin-forms-app-able-to-open-specific-file-types